# Как отсортировать объекты по категориям в зависимости от даты (Java)?

Tags: java, map, calendar

Привет. Есть Map, в которой находятся имена объектов и даты их создания. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от даты создания имя объекта попадало в List, соответствующий определенному промежутку времени. Т.е., например, объекты, которые созданы сегодня лежат в одном листе, те, что вчера - в другом, на прошлой неделе - в третьем.

Реализовал это через большое число вложенных if'ов, но получилось как-то громоздко, ощущение, что можно сделать попроще.

Советовали удалять элементы из Map, тогда число проверок снизится, но я не понимаю, как удаление уже обработанных пар поможет избежать лишних проверок... 
Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Если дата - это ключ, то будет эффективно использование TreeMap, со свои компаратором. Останется, после приведения типа, раскидать по листам.

Comment: Как раз проблема в том, что уникальны здесь лишь имена объектов, а даты могут быть одинаковы. Потому и нужно их как бы по категориям раскидать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись по Map и каждую дату создания преобразовать в некий объект-интервал, который будет использоваться в качестве ключа в новой Map, в которой значениями будут искомые списки имён объектов. Что-то вроде этого:

```
private static Object DateTimeToInterval(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
  return LocalDate.from(dateTime).toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, LocalDateTime> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("Obj1", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 5, 25, 15, 30, 1));
  map.put("Obj2", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 5, 25, 18, 20, 3));
  map.put("Obj5", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 9, 12, 23, 10, 8));
  map.put("Obj3", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 7, 28, 20, 50, 4));
  map.put("Obj8", LocalDateTime.of(2016, 7, 28, 21, 10, 9));

  System.out.println(map);

  Map<Object, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();

  for (String name: map.keySet()) {
    Object interval = DateTimeToInterval(map.get(name));
    List<String> list = newMap.get(interval);

    if (list == null) {
      list = new ArrayList<String>();
      newMap.put(interval, list);
    }
    list.add(name);
  }

  System.out.println(newMap);
}
```